# Способ стилизации навигации

Tags: html, css

Такой способ стилизации, имеет место быть или лучше делать по-другому?

Еще пробовал задавать элементам `a` блочный тип, но применить к элементу `a` псевдокласс `:first-child` не получилось, только к элементам `li`.

```css
nav ul {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

nav li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #b2b2b2;
}

.top-menu {
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.top-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  padding: 0 33px;
}

.top-menu li:first-child {
  padding: 0 42px;
}

/*
.top-menu a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0px 33px;
 font-weight: 300;
}
*/

.top-menu .active {
  background: #29c5e6;
}

.top-menu .active a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="top-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">About us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Partners</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Customers</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: вполне приемлемый способ стилизации!

Comment: А почему бы и нет. Неплохая реализация

Comment: имеет место быть)

Comment: а что вызвало сомнения?

Comment: Только учусь, думаю у всех новичков так) а к элементам (a) нельзя применить псевдокласс из-за родительских-дочерних отношений? так как сам элемент a дочерний.

Comment: @John-n, можно и к ссылке применить, но т.к. она в li одна (ссылка) то `:first-child` просто нет смысла применять. если бы в li было несколько ссылок: `<li><a href="#">...</a><a href="#">...</a> ... </li>` тогда да.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Использовать `inline-block` для стилизации навигации на сайте, вполне приемлемая практика:

```css
nav ul {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

nav li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #b2b2b2;
}

.top-menu {
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.top-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  padding: 0 33px;
}

.top-menu li:first-child {
  padding: 0 42px;
}

/*
.top-menu a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0px 33px;
 font-weight: 300;
}
*/

.top-menu .active {
  background: #29c5e6;
}

.top-menu .active a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="top-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">About us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Partners</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Customers</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

> но применить к элементу a псевдокласс :first-child не получилось

Если я правильно понимаю, то Вы хотели сделать так:

```
.top-menu li a:first-child {
  padding: 0 42px;
}
```

Если да, то такой вариант возможен если в `li` находится несколько ссылок, т.е. если бы html выглядел так:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About us</a>
  ...
</li>
```

Для Вашего же примера можно задать:

```
.top-menu li:first-child a {
  padding: 0 42px;
}
```

Т.е. стили для ссылки внутри первой лишки:

```css
nav ul {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

nav li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #b2b2b2;
}

.top-menu {
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}

.top-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  /* padding: 0 33px; */
}

.top-menu li:first-child a {
  padding: 0 42px;
}


.top-menu a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0px 33px;
 font-weight: 300;
}


.top-menu .active {
  background: #29c5e6;
}

.top-menu .active a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="top-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">About us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Partners</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Customers</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

Другие варианты реализации навигации.

1. `float: left;`

```css
nav ul {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

nav li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #b2b2b2;
}

.top-menu {
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top-menu li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.top-menu a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0px 42px;
 font-weight: 300;
}

.top-menu li+li a {
  padding: 0 33px;
}


.top-menu .active {
  background: #29c5e6;
}

.top-menu .active a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="top-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">About us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Partners</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Customers</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

2. `display: flex;`

```css
nav ul {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

nav li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #b2b2b2;
}

.top-menu {
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;  
}

.top-menu a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0px 42px;
 font-weight: 300;
}

.top-menu li+li a {
  padding: 0 33px;
}


.top-menu .active {
  background: #29c5e6;
}

.top-menu .active a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="top-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">About us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Partners</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Customers</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

3. `display: table;`

```css
nav ul {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}

nav li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #b2b2b2;
}

.top-menu {
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-family: "Oswald";
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table;
}

.top-menu li {
  display: table-cell;
}

.top-menu a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0px 42px;
 font-weight: 300;
}

.top-menu li+li a {
  padding: 0 33px;
}


.top-menu .active {
  background: #29c5e6;
}

.top-menu .active a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="top-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">About us</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Partners</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Customers</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

...

Comment: Спасибо, за такой содержательный ответ )